# Use of "webmaster" title

Tags: terminology

Ok.. There are real questions out there about real problems to be answered.. but, I decided to throw this one.. since sometimes it helps to chill a little from everyday's stuff.

My mind was wandering around the term "webmaster" I read the Wikipedia, I read some stack overflow posts about it. And yet I see it still confuses some people. Some guys proposed that if you developed a web page and configure it's web server, that'd be a webmaster role. And more or less it fits with the Wikipedia description.
Certainly, due to the evolution of the web, these roles have become individual new ones (developers, sysadmins, designers, etc..)

My scenario and question is different. Suppose one owns a server (physical) and installs, configures and administers already existing web apps (WordPress, etc...)

That role, could also be "webmaster" or it shifts to something else? I kinda doubt a little, because there is no developing part.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: This question is out of scope for Superuser.  **"since sometimes it helps to chill a little from everyday's stuff."** - The last thing that happens, for me personally when i read this type of question, is me chilling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster defines "Webmaster"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/webmaster) as,

> a person responsible for the creation or maintenance of a Web site especially for a company or organization

So if you are responsible for the production or preservation of a website, then you are a webmaster.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a point of view Tom!

Comment: @LuisGarnicaGuilarte Happy to help, if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that green tick:)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot!